# Can I have Oracle primary 11.2.0.1 and standby 11.2.0.3?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, upgrade, standby

Can I have data guard system like:

Primary: 11.2.0.1 
Standby: 11.2.0.3

In logical standby ?

In physical standby versions(releases) must be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The physical standby database must be physically the same as the primary database and this means the versions must be identical.

A logical standby database can be any version, depending on how it is implemented. With 3rd party tools you can go from v10 to v12 and back. The restrictions here are on the data types that are to be replicated.

If this is for an upgrade, you start with a physical standby database, convert that to a logical standby for the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Physical:

"Differences between the primary server(s) and the standby server(s) are always supported as long as the Oracle software installed on all servers is of the same Oracle Platform as defined above, is certified to run on each server, and is the **same Oracle Database Release and Patch Set**."

Logical:

"Differences between the primary server(s) and the standby server(s) are always permitted as long as the Oracle software installed on all servers is of the same Oracle Platform as defined above, and is certified to run on each server, and is the **same Oracle Database Release and Patch Set**. (Note that beginning with Oracle Database 10.1.0.3, SQL Apply supports configurations where the standby database is operating at a later Oracle Database Release or Patch Set, **for the purpose of performing a database rolling upgrade**.)"

So the short answer is: no (even if it is technically possible).

Comment: it would be useful if you add a reference to the text you are citing.

Answer (score -5):

Sometimes it is better to read before making advice.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17022/upgrades.htm#CIHJIICA

B.4 Modifying the COMPATIBLE Initialization Parameter After Upgrading

When you upgrade to a new release of Oracle Database, certain new features might make your database incompatible with your previous release. Oracle Database enables you to control the compatibility of your database with the COMPATIBLE initialization parameter.

After the upgrade is complete, you can increase the setting of the COMPATIBLE initialization parameter to the maximum level for the new Oracle Database release. When you are certain that you no longer need the ability to downgrade your database back to its original version, set the COMPATIBLE initialization parameter based on the compatibility level you want for your new database.

In a Data Guard configuration, if you decide to increase the setting of the COMPATIBLE initialization parameter after upgrading, then it is important that you perform the following steps in the order shown (note that the standby database should have a COMPATIBLE setting equal to, or higher than, the primary):

**Increase the value of the COMPATIBLE initialization parameter on all standby databases in the configuration first, as follows:**

Ensure that apply is current on the standby database(s).

On one instance of each standby database, execute the following SQL statement:

ALTER SYSTEM SET COMPATIBLE= SCOPE=SPFILE;
If Redo Apply or SQL Apply is running, then stop them.

Restart all instances of the standby database(s).

If you previously stopped Redo Apply or SQL Apply, then restart them.

Increase the value of the COMPATIBLE initialization parameter on the primary database, as follows:

On one instance of the primary database, execute the following SQL statement:

ALTER SYSTEM SET COMPATIBLE= SCOPE=SPFILE;
Restart all instances of the primary database.

Comment: Except your answer actually has nothing to do with the question!